# python: good one time token generation strategies

Tags: python, encryption, one-time-password

So I studied around a bit and found out that the term "One Time Password" usually seems to refer to time-synced hardware clocks.

We don't have that. We are creating a workflow where staff may sign up a client, who then receives an email with a link to login, valid only once (the client will have to supply some additional, weak and simple personal information such as phone number in order to login)

So strictly speaking this is not a OTP, but probably more somethink like a One Time Token.

What are good strategies for this case? My main uncertainty is about if I need to encrypt this token in the DBSo far I've identified:

- Generate a one time token with `uuid.uuid4()`. This is pretty simple and easy. However, no encryption.
- Generate a one time token and save it encrypted to the DB, then encode it HTML safe and send it with the link.

I wonder if there is any need to encrypt the token. Generally of course we need to encrypt passwords in the DB. But this token will be sent over HTTP anyways (base64 encoded I guess) so I don't see the advantage of encrypting it....

Comment: The uuid is quick and dirty solution, especially if you require another piece of info for the first login.  Also suggest setting an expiration date (i usually keep them in a db table with a created date), so encryption is probably overkill. I also suggest requiring HTTPS for any communication involving credentials.

Comment: yes @dbugger, I agree with your analysis.